# Thread dead lock is occurred on unmarshalling into java object

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, jaxb

Hi I am using HttpURLConnection to send request for server and the  XML inputstream response is converted into java object by javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller on multiple thread environment. It's working fine. But at some point, (ie) when unmarshalling the inputstream, the thread was blocked. I didn't get any exception at that time.

After invoking convertStreamToObject method,the thread is blocked.

Please any one help me to fix the issue. The code is below

```
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
        connection.setReadTimeout(1500);
        try {
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            OPERATION_LOGS.error("IOException in sendRequest()",e);
        }if(inputStream != null){

                T response = convertStreamToObject(inputStream, responseObjType);
        }
    } catch(Exception e ) {
        OPERATION_LOGS.error("Exception in sendRequest()",e);
    }   


    public <K> K convertStreamToObject(InputStream inputStream, Class<K> type) {
        try {

            return  (K) XMLUtility.parseXML(inputStream, type);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            OPERATION_LOGS.error(EXCEPTION , e);
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static <T> T parseXML(InputStream inputStream, Class<T> type) {


        T beanObject = null;
        Unmarshaller unmarshObj = null;

        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);

            if (context != null) {
                unmarshObj = context.createUnmarshaller();
            }

            if (unmarshObj != null) {
                // Converting the xml into corresponding bean
                beanObject = (T) unmarshObj.unmarshal(inputStream);
            }
            OPERATION_LOGS.debug("Response XML:" + encodeXML(beanObject, type));

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            OPERATION_LOGS.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        return beanObject;
    }
```

Comment: So your saying multiple threads may be converting streams to beans?  Have you tried making your convertStreamToObject synchronized?

Comment: Can yo tell me that Is the problem with multiple thread or by jaxb Unmarshaller ?

Comment: try public synchronized <K> K convertStreamToObject(InputStream inputStream, Class<K> type)

Comment: Hi I used synchronized also. But it's not helped me. The Unmarshall hangs and it's not return value. I got link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949813/jaxb-hangs-while-unmarshaling-socket-stream/11052106#11052106
But I wanted to fix the issue by jaxb